# Implode error on my srcipt

Tags: php, implode

This is my script:

```
function save($data) {
$fopen = fopen("filebaru.txt", "a+");
fwrite($fopen, implode(",\n",file_get_contents($data)));
fclose($fopen);
}


$files = glob('C:\Users\dark\Desktop\dumped\New folder\*.txt');
foreach($files as $file) {
save($file);
}
```

Shows error:

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in   C:\Users\dark\Desktop\dumped\New folder\gabung.php on line 4

Can anoyone help me to solve it.

Comment: `file_get_contents` does not return an array.

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents` returns a string and `implode` requires an array.  If you want each line in an array to `implode` then use `file`:

```
fwrite($fopen, implode(",\n", file($data)));
```

Since you are adding newlines you probably want `file($data, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`.

You could save a lot of opening and closing of the file by moving the `foreach` into the function.

Comment: then how can we get new line each word that implode , with this code :
fwrite($fopen, implode(",\n",file($data)));

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Example?

Comment: file 1 :
aqsa@email.com
file 2 : 
bro@eemail.com

then i use that script to merge as 1 file txt like :
file 3 with output :
aqsa@email.com
bro@eemail.com

but using this code : fwrite($fopen, implode(",\n", file($data)));
they output show like this :
aqsa@email.combro@eemail.com

and not at new lines

Comment: The browser and some apps like notepad won't render newlines.  Do a view source on the browser page, or if needed to view in a browser use `<br>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, `file_get_contents` doesn't return an array, it returns a string. If you take a look at the php documentation for [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it expects the `glue` for joining pieces of the `array`, as well as the `array` you wish to join.

If you are looking to replace all commas followed by a new line, you ought to check out [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). It takes the `search` (`,\n` in your case), what to `replace` the search with (in your case an empty string: `''`), and the string you want to adjust (the `subject`).

In your case the following line of code would work for writing in your `save` function.

```
fwrite($fopen, str_replace(',\n', '', file_get_contents($data)));
```